# JavaFX Tree View Height According to Content

Tags: treeview, javafx

I have number of treeviews in VBox. 
I want treeview to take a height based on the number of nodes visible.
Say if I collapse root node of treeview then height of that treeview should also change.[image: Image of three tree views in a vbox]

In the case of this image Item0 shows 7 subitems and then there is a lot of whitespace and then Item1 starts, Item1 is collapsed now , so Item2 should start immediately below Item1.

Please tell me what is the right way of doing this.

Comment: Did you found any solution? I also have the same problem.

Comment: Have a tree node with root node as empty not visible and have one tree view instead of multiple tree views (if possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    VBox treeContainer = new VBox();

    TreeItem<String> hiddenRootItem = new TreeItem<String>();
    TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<String>(hiddenRootItem);
    tree.setShowRoot(false);

    treeContainer.getChildren().add(tree);

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<String>("Item " + j);
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        String[] names = {"SubItem1", "SubItem2", "SubItem3", "SubItem4", "SubItem5", "SubItem6", "SubItem7",};
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<String>(names[i]);
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }
        hiddenRootItem.getChildren().add(rootItem);
    }

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(treeContainer);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```